# Subgroup of direct product containing direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I was reading Milne's notes on class field theory. On page 22, while giving an example to the fact that every subgroup of $K^{\times}$, where K is a local field of characteristic $p\neq 0$, is not open, he makes the following remark:

Choose a subgroup of finite index in $\underset{\mathbb N}\prod \mathbb F_p$, which contains $\underset{\mathbb N}\bigoplus \mathbb F_p$.

I am not able to figure out why such a subgroup exists? Please help.

Comment: He refers to Proposition 7.26 in his field theory notes. The lemma before that applies here: view the product as a $\Bbb F_p$ vector space and choose a basis containing a basis of the direct sum and then omit a few basis vectors

Comment: Realized it after posting the question. Thanks, @leoli1.